# Programmatically post on Facebook group

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to develop a little app for Facebook, and I'm facing a problem with the API.
After a few searches, I started to think the graph API doesn't allow to do what I wanna do...

Basically, I want to post automatically a message on a group wall. I have a website on which people can post their message. This community also has a Facebook group, and my point is to automatically post a copy of messages from the website, on the Facebook group. Each time a new message is submitted on the website, of course.

I know that apps and pages can’t post on a group wall by themself. 
So, I considered creating a Facebook account, working like a bot, to post my messages on the group. I guess I have to get a long-lived access token for this user, and renew it manually when it expire. I don't want to have to login myself manually, but it's not a big deal if I have to renew my token time to time.

Is that even possible? Is there a better trick to do that?

I'm a bit confused by the Facebook API, and I'm sorry for this question. Even more because of the changes on the fb API...a lot of answers through the web are now deprecated. What I am looking for is a start -an idea- to be able to develop my app.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is really simple:

First, You'll need `access_token`n with the `offline_access` permission (this way it will last for 2 months)

Then, store this access_token somewhere and do:

**Post to group wall:**

```
$fbk = new Facebook(...);
$bfk->setAccessToken($yourBotAccessToken);
$postId = $fbk->api("/$fbGroupId/feed/",'post',$message);
```

You can even post replies to the first post:

```
$fbk->api('/'.$postid.'/comments/','post',$reply);
```

Comment: Is this still valid with the current API 2.8?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know